# Is there a better (smoother) transition I can use?

Tags: javascript, css, css-animations

I am currently making an 'animated' background for a website where the background image scrolls through after an hour and then resets to its original position to start again. I am currently making the image to appear to be a 360 degree image through some photoshop trickery. Though when testing the scrolling image, I noticed that the image "jerks" into position for each part of the transition. Im looking for something that will be much smoother than the image 'jumping' from pixel to pixel but still remaining very slow. If there is a better option through javascript I am definetly all ears.

Here is what I am currently using for my CSS (div background image sizing will change once the picture Im actually using is finished):

```
*{
    margin:0; 
    padding:0; 
    border: 0; 
    line-height: 100%; 
    font-size: 100%;
}

#container {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: black;
}
#center {
    background-image:url(http://farm4.staticflickr.com/3768/11633218256_30a04f01c3_o.png);
    background-size: contain;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position:absolute;
    animation: scroll 3600s;
    animation-timing-function:linear;
    animation-fill-mode:forwards;
    animation-iteration-count:infinite;
}
@keyframes scroll {
0% {right:0%;}
100%{right:100%;}
}
```

Comment: Hard to know what you mean. Can you reproduce the problem in a simple self contained example here? http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: @AlexWayne With the nature of how the background is supposed to work and the scale that needs to be reproduced, it would be very hard to show you what I mean in jsfiddle.net HOWEVER, here is a Dropbox link with my POC content so you can see what I mean: https://www.dropbox.com/s/ll8c7ydgbbodj4f/hexcenter5.html

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You could use jQuery. This gives a nice smooth animation and would also be cross browser compatible.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Animate</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="container">
        <div id="center"></div>
    </div>
    <!--The following gets the jQuery code from the jQuery CDN and loads it to your page-->
    <!--This needs to be called before any jQuery code will run-->
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        /*
        The following uses jQuerys animate method
        The part before the first period decides which element we want to target,
        in your case the div with ID center. Next call animate and tell it what to 
        animate. We want to change the right position to 100% from whatever it is
        initially. The number following that is the amount of time it will take your
        animation to complete in milliseconds.
        */
        $("#center").animate({right: "100%"}, 50000);
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

- Edit: at such a slow moving speed it appears jerky as well, but not as jerky. If you slow the speed down it will look much better.

Comment: I actually havent gotten to the point of learning JQuery yet. I know I have to add a reference library but Im not entirely sure how to do that yet.

Comment: i will edit my answer to clarify even if you decide to go a different route

Comment: Thanks, Im actually probably more interested in the jquery route if it produces a better result. If anything ill need to learn jquery anyways to go the babylon.js route and use opengl if need to. Either way I can use your answer, so thanks!

Comment: A javascript solution where a pure CSS solution will most likely do isn't a great idea.

Comment: Well it would be cross browser compatible and the CSS solution would not be and moving at such a slow speed the jQuery solution is smoother.

Comment: I think, Mr. Wayne, that if you are to down vote my answer then you ought to come up with an answer that can replace it.